# There exist $c(c\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ s.t $2 \int _{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{f(c)}{c} $

Tags: real-analysis

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Let $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f'(x)>0,f''(x)<0$ on $[0,1]$

Q: Under the proposition is true of false?

There exist $c(c\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ s.t
$$2 \int _{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\frac{f(c)}{c} $$
I was using mean value theorem but it is difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can be written as $f(x)= x h(x)$, where $h$ is $C^1$ (Taylor integral formula for the residue, etc.), and you're asked to find whether

$\int_0^1 2x h(x) dx$ is between $h(1/2)$ and $h(1).$ I.e. it applies to your function $h$, but not for the whole interval, and actually for a restricted one.

You may see that $h(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function, $h(0)=f'(0)$, and $h(1)=1$, so the issue is the following: once we apply the mean value theorem

$$\int_0^1 2x h(x) dx= h(c),$$

and it follows that one may take $c> 1/2$ if and only if $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx < f(1/2)=\frac{h(1/2)}{2}.$$

Comment: I forgot to add: from the picture you may notice the behaviour of the continuous function (actually, $C^1$) $h(x)=f(x)/x$; you may actually prove that this function is decreasing by using the definition of a convex (in this case, concave) function, but an image is worth 1000 words :)